# Reply to list in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

The `SmartReply` button in Thunderbird give a "Reply to list" option when it detects that the email belongs to a list. Yet it sometimes fails to detect the presence of a list. In my case for instance, emails received through a googlegroup are detected, but not emails received from a mailing list internal to my job.

My question: How does the detection of list of the `SmartReply` button works? And is there a way to tweak this detection, telling Thunderbird that a given address is a list?

Answer (score 1):

I've posted the question on Mozilla support forum, and I got the answer that [there is no way to tell Thunderbird that a specific address is a list](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1105146).

Comment: An addition regarding how this thing works: The message must have a "List-Post" header in order to trigger the display of this button. This is from the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Thunderbird/Thunderbird_3_for_users